# Hide toolbar for Storybook docs

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon, storybook-addon-doc

I would like to hide the toolbar only for docs pages. I tried the configuration [shown here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/web-components/configure/features-and-behavior) but this hides toolbar items for both stories and docs pages. And I still see globals in the docs toolbar as seen below:

[image: Storybook]

Any possibility to configure it to hide toolbar completely on docs pages?

**Note**: I am on the latest beta version: `7.0.0-beta.25`

Comment: Did you solved this?? I also stuck on this

Comment: @SpookyJelly nope.

Comment: I'd drilled this a bit. It seems there is no answer while we use the 7.x version.. Now I quiet this. Hope you got a solution in otherway